# NSDate date with timezone and no localization of the formating

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate

I need to get the date+time+timezone of the device without **any** localized text (I was getting arabic letters and different time formats from different countries using [nsdate date] )

Input code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 

What I get: ۱۳۹۲-۰۲-۳۱ ۱۰:۰۳:۱۶ 0000 - 

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
another example (bad) 1392-02-31 10:04:56 0000 
Desired Result: 22-05-2013 22:50:00 +0002 (day-month-year hour-minute-second timezone)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Show your input, code and desired result plus what you actually get. NSDate has no localisation information, its how you present it on screen that counts.

Comment: Input code: 
nsdate *date = [nsdate date];
What I get: ۱۳۹۲-۰۲-۳۱ ۱۰:۰۳:۱۶  0000 - another example (bad) 1392-02-31 10:04:56  0000

Desired Result: 
22-05-2013 22:50:00 +0002 (day-month-year hour-minute-second timezone)

Comment: getting the date to a string (to send to a log) nsstring *dateString = [nsstring stringwithformat:@"%@",[nsdate date]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code to convert it to your system time.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    [formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSDate * TodaysDate=Date you want to convert;
    NSString *dateStrToSave =[formatter1 stringFromDate:TodaysDate];
```

and let me know if it works or not.